# Detect Salesforce edition and/or capabilities from Apex/VisualForce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

From within an Apex class, how can I detect the Edition (ie, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited). More specifically, is there an API to retrieve the capabilities (or lack thereof) for the user's edition?

The problem I am trying to solve is that from the Group/Professional edition, users cannot access the custom Web Services in my app, receiving the error LOGIN_OAUTH_API_DISABLED. Is there a way to detect whether this is going to work from within Apex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following SOQL to determine the Organization's license type:

```
SELECT OrganizationType FROM Organization
```

For Professional it will return "Professional Edition". This is detailed on the [Organization object page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Are there any specific capabilities you're looking to discover? There's no way to determine the edition (and this would be mostly a red herring if you could). A lot of differences end up being reflected in the data model, and you can discover that using the [describe features](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm).

If you want to check from apex if your web services is enabled/available, then you could use apex callouts to try and make a call to it (and FWIW, the error code is from OAuth, and not from your apex web service)

Comment: Thanks superfell, I have updated my question with the specific capability I am trying to detect.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. I gather there is no easy solution to this problem, it kind of confirmed what I already knew ;-) In any case thanks for offering your thoughts!